# BASH parameters with wildcard

Tags: bash, parameters, wildcard

I'm trying to do a bash script that will find & copy similar files to a destination directory.

For example, I'm passing a parameter 12300 to a script and I want to copy all files that start with 12300... to a new directory.

like this:

```
sh script.sh 12300
```

and here's the script:

```
if [ -f /home/user/bashTest/$@*.jpg ]
then
    cp /home/user/bashTest/$@*.jpg /home/user/bashTest/final/
fi
```

This just doesn't work. I have tried all kinds of solutions but nothing has worked.
**The question is: How can I use wildcard with parameter?**

Comment: First off, if this is bash and not bourne shell, execute it with `bash`, not with `sh`.  Second, read the bash man page that describes "`Special Parameters`"  Visualize what would happen if someone were to run `yourscript.sh ".;rm -rf "`.

Comment: yes. I'll have a look. thanks

Comment: It is not necessarily bash.  Writing code with bashisms when they're unnecessary only limits portability and bashisms aren't even that useful in this example.  On the other hand bash will run sh code but not vice versa, so if you do include bashisms or only test with bash then please do use #!/bin/bash on the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're checking for multiple files with `-f` or `-e` it can get nasty.  I recommend [kenfallon's blog](http://kenfallon.com/finding-if-one-or-more-files-exist-in-a-directory-using-bash/).  This is something like what he would recommend:

```
#! /bin/bash

ls -l /home/user/bashTest/$1*.jpg > /dev/null
if [ "$?" = "0" ]
then
    cp /home/user/bashTest/$1*.jpg /home/user/bashTest/final/
fi
```

Not sure how the `$@` would play in here, or if it's required.

Comment: thanks for your help. This worked. And thanks for the link to the kenfallon's blog :)

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the thing that expands to the parameters in `{}`, i.e. `/home/user/bashTest/${@}*.jpg`. You should use `$1` instead of `$@` in your case however as you only seem to be able to handle the first argument given to the script. `$1` expands to the first argument, `$2` to the second etc.

You also need a loop to iterate over all files that this glob expands to, e.g.

```
for file in /tmp/${@}*.jpg
do
    if [ -f $file ]
    then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still says 
  "  [: 4: /home/user/bashTest/40022.jpg: unexpected operator"  SCRIPT after modification: 

    if [ -f /home/user/bashTest/${1}*.jpg ]
      then
        cp /home/user/bashTest/${1}*.jpg /home/user/bashTest/final/
    fi

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work because your glob expands to more than one filename. I'll edit the answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash    
cp /home/user/bashTest/${1}*.jpg /home/user/bashTest/final/
```

#### Discussion

- In this case, a simple `cp` command will do
- I have tested it with files that have embedded spaces

Answer (score 1):

Write this in script.sh:

> cp /home/user/bashTest/$1*.jpg /home/user/bashTest/final/

That's all.

UPD. @macduff solution usefull too.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all of them in your $HOME directory and subdirectories (you may wish to tweak find to follow/not follow symlinks and/or adjust the $HOME base directory where it starts the search)

```
#!/bin/sh
DEST=/your/dest/folder

for FILE in `find "$HOME" -iname "$1"*`;do
  [ -f "$FILE" ] && mv "$FILE" "$DEST/$FILE"
  #or ln -s ...if you want to keep it in its original location
done

if you want to do multiple patterns using $@

for PATTERN in $@; do
for FILE in `find "$HOME" -iname "$PATTERN"*`;do
  [ -f "$FILE" ] && mv "$FILE" "$DEST/$FILE"
done
done
```